# How to resolve Error: "Uncaught Error: This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided." when use Cartesian Chart.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, chart.js, cartesian-coordinates

I have been working with the Chart.js in order to render a json data into cartesian time chart. The data is converted from List<tuple<string, int>> from a service class into json data where the data is made up of Date and time as string type and count as an int. This part of the code is done in view (cshtml).

From the json data, it was passed to the script part of the cshtml in order to render the charts, the first chart is rendered for the Pie chart using different data type (Not part of the question) but when it comes to the line chart for rendering the cartesian it causes an error saying "Uncaught Error: This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided" and it is called/appear when it tries to render the new Chart(ctx...) part of the code in the line chart function. What am I doing wrong here and how can I solve it?

```
@{
    var ID = Model.FirstOrDefault()?.ID; // Get the ID of the first item in the list;
    var DetailCounts = await Service.GetDetailChartDataAsync(ID.Value);
    var DetailCounts2 = await Service.GetDetailChartDataAsync(ID.Value);
    var jsonDetailData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DetailCounts);
    var jsonDetailData2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DetailCounts2);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row custom-row-height my-auto">
                <div class="col" id="DetailChartdiv">
                    <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" class="container-fluid">
                        <header class="fw-bold"> Current Information</header>
                        <canvas id="DetailChart">
                        </canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row custom-row-height my-auto">
            <div class="col" id="DetailChart2div">
                <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" class="container-fluid">
                    <header class="fw-bold">Current Information</header>
                    <canvas id="DetailChart2"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        // Retrieve the JSON data from the hidden field
        var jsonDicData = @Html.Raw(jsonDetailData);
        var jsonDicData2 = @Html.Raw(jsonDetailData2);

        // Parse the data and prepare it for the line chart
        const parsedData2 = jsonDicData2.map(entry => ({
            t: new Date(entry.Item1),
            y: entry.Item2
        }));

        // Function to render the pie chart using Chart.js
        function renderPieChart(data, canvasid) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasid);
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: {
                    labels: Object.keys(data),
                    datasets: [{
                        data: Object.values(data),
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    // Additional options and configurations for the pie chart can be added here
                    plugins: {
                        colorschemes: {
                            scheme: 'brewer.Paired12' // Example color scheme
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Function to render the line chart using Chart.js
        function renderLineChart(data, canvasid) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasid);
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Count',
                        data: data,
                        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit: 'day' // Adjust according to your data
                            }
                        },
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Call the rendering functions with the retrieved JSON data
        renderPieChart(jsonDicData, 'DetailChart');
        renderLineChart(parsedData2, 'DetailChart2');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my output json data that are being used in the chart is the following:

```
{Item1: '03/08/2023 07:46:11', Item2: 0}
```

and the parsed is the following:

```
{t: Wed Mar 08 2023 07:46:11 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), y: 0}
```

I am also using the latest version of the Chart.js package.

***Edit 1:***

I have added the following packages:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

However, I am getting the same outcome (Error).

***Edit 2:***

If I used the following code:

```
    function renderLineChart(parsedData, canvasid) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasid);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (!window.chartInstances) {
            window.chartInstances = {}; // Create a global object to store chart instances
        }

        if (!window.chartInstances[canvasid]) {
            // Create a new Chart.js instance if it doesn't exist
            window.chartInstances[canvasid] = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Count',
                        data: parsedData,
                        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                        fill: false
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit: 'day'
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Date'
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Count'
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Update the existing Chart.js instance with new data and options
            window.chartInstances[canvasid].data.labels = Object.keys(parsedData);
            window.chartInstances[canvasid].data.datasets[0].data = Object.values(parsedData);
            window.chartInstances[canvasid].update();
        }
    }
```

I got the following plot below:
[image: Output plot]

I am also getting the following errors:

```
Invalid scale configuration for scale: xAxes
Invalid scale configuration for scale: yAxes
```

***Edit 3:***

```
    function renderLineChart(parsedData, canvasid) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasid);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (!window.chartInstances) {
            window.chartInstances = {}; // Create a global object to store chart instances
        }

        if (!window.chartInstances[canvasid]) {
            // Create a new Chart.js instance if it doesn't exist
            window.chartInstances[canvasid] = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Count',
                        data: parsedData,
                        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                        fill: false
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        x: [{
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit: 'day' // Adjust according to your data
                            },
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Date'
                            }
                        }],
                        y: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            },
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Count'
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Update the existing Chart.js instance with new data and options
            window.chartInstances[canvasid].data.labels = Object.keys(parsedData);
            window.chartInstances[canvasid].data.datasets[0].data = Object.values(parsedData);
            window.chartInstances[canvasid].update();
        }
    }
```

still same error and output

***Edit 4:***

I managed to get the plot to present the data, however, how can I get the x-axis label to render the date and time?

```
// Function to render the line chart using Chart.js
function renderLineChart(data, canvasid) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasid);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Count',
                data: data,
                borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'hour' // Adjust according to your data
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[image: Output Plot2]

***Edit 5:***
Will it be possible to render custom tooltipformat? see my following line function:

```
// Function to render the line chart using Chart.js
            function renderLineChart(data1, data2, canvasid) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasid);
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            
                console.log("Rendering line chart...");

                // Destroy old line chart if it exists
                if (window.chartInstances[canvasid]) {
                    console.log('Destroying old line chart...');
                    window.chartInstances[canvasid].destroy();
                }

                console.log("Creating new line chart...");
                if (!window.chartInstances[canvasid]) 
                {
                    window.chartInstances = {};
                    // Create a new Chart.js instance if it doesn't exist
                    window.chartInstances[canvasid] = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Total  Count (1)',
                            data: data1.map(item => ({
                                x: item.x,
                                y: item.y,
                                string1: item.string1,
                                string2: item.string2
                            })),
                            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Total  Count (2)',
                            data: data2.map(item => ({
                                x: item.x,
                                y: item.y,
                                string1: item.string1,
                                string2: item.string2
                            })),
                            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                        }]
                    },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                x: {
                                type: 'time',  // Use time scale for x-axis
                                time: {
                                    tooltipFormat: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' // Format for tooltip display
                                    displayFormats: {
                                        second: 'dd/MM HH:mm:ss',  // Format for x-axis labels
                                    },
                                },
                                title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    text: 'Timestamp',
                                    },
                                },
                                y: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    title:{
                                        display: true,
                                        text: 'Counts'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            plugins: {
                                tooltip: {
                                    callbacks: {
                                        tooltipFormat: function (context) {
                                        const xValue = context.parsed.x;
                                        const yValue = context.parsed.y;
                                        const dataset = context.dataset;
                                        const dataItem = dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                                        const string1 = dataItem.string1 || '';
                                        const string2 = dataItem.string2 || '';
                                        const label2 = 'Current Data:';
                                        return `${label2} ${xValue} - ${yValue} - ${string1} - ${string2}`;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // Update the existing Chart.js instance with new data and options
                    window.chartInstances[canvasid].data.datasets[0].data = data1;
                    window.chartInstances[canvasid].data.datasets[1].data = data2;
                    window.chartInstances[canvasid].update();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Start by including an [adapter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters). All adapters have instructions on how to install and/or link to their distribution code, and since you're getting chart.js from CDN, you can do the same with the adapter, see for instance [date-fns](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns#cdn)

Comment: @kikon I have added your recommendation but still I am getting the same error. See the edit part of the question.

Comment: I don't get it - it should not give the same error if you did include the adapter; check again your setup. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr12zfd6/) with the line part of your code as a thing to compare to. I did change `t` to `x` in the parsed data, but without that it just shows nothing, there is no error.

Comment: @Kikon, I am not sure what could be the cause error, I have followed your steps and changed the t into x, however, I get the same error. But I managed to use another way, see the edited part of the question.

Comment: No, that is not good, `xAxes: [{....}]` doesn't work in version 4 of chart.js. It simply shows something because the scale options are not parsed, so it doesn't attempt to use a time axis

Comment: In the browser session where you get that error, if you look at the page source (that is post-razor), can you see the adapter CDN link?

Comment: @kikon if you mean in the Page section then yes. I can see a folder for the adapter. I modified the one code to the third edit of the question.

Comment: No. I mean in the html source taken from the browser, do you see the CDN link `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>`? Also, from the network tab of your browser console (dev tools) do you see the file `chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js` being transferred after the file `chart.js`?

Comment: @kikon Yes I can see it in the network

Comment: I have no explanation - here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hapx1kjg/) with the code in your `renderLineChart` and it works fine! BTW, you forgot the erroneous arrays in the scale configuration - that should have given an 'invalid scale confirguration' error, never a missing adapter error! Try sharing in a fiddle or something similar the post-razor code from the browser's "view page source"

Comment: @Kikon I managed to get it to work and render the chart but why am I not getting the x-axis label for date and time?

Comment: I don't know ... the configuration is still not OK, but I don't know how; the code looks good. Try to compare it with the latest fiddle I sent, or even better, fork the fiddle and try to make it behave like your code. I would need a running example to debug hands-on.

Comment: @Kikon okay, another question, say if you have a lot of records to render into the chart is there a way to render chart once the it manages to process the all records or if maybe would it be best to keep the page loading until the all the data is rendered then load the page?

Comment: Depends, if the server is relatively slow to produce data it may make sense to do an incremental update, but that's rather difficult to implement and not certain to improve things dramatically, so I'd start with the simplest way and if it's not good enough see if you can improve it. Also see if [data decimation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/decimation.html) might be useful for your case.

Comment: @kikon, another question is it possible to customise the tooltipformat to display custom message? I have it set to tooltipFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'', but I want to set tooltipFormat to display the follwoing
`data: data1.map(item => ({
                                x: item.x,
                                y: item.y,
                                datastring1: item.datastring1,
                                datastring2: item.datastring2
                            })),` to display x which is date, y which is count and rest are strings?

Comment: yes, check [tooltip callbacks docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) and [an example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/content.html). For a specific issue related to the tooltip, consider asking another question here on SO, I'll be looking for that

Comment: @kikon thank you for the help, I managed to create a function similar to example that suited my need. Thank you for the help.